# Hide Page/Tab from QTWidget - QT 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.5, qtwidgets

i need to hide tabs from a existing project in QT, i **don't want to delete the code** because i have to set parameters on that code, the Application relay on that too. Seems like QT hasn't built-in hide(); function, i tried to edit stylesheet to make it smaller, but doesn't work too, i've looked on the internet and seems like this is a known issue. Does somebody have some tricks to avoid this?

Only thing i was able to come up with is:

```
ui->TabObject->setEnabled(false);
```

basically i disable objects in the tab to make them not usable by the user, but this is not a good thing for the whole UI.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by calling `QTabWidget::removeTab(index)` - this removes the tab from the QTabWidget, but does not delete the tab's QWidget.

Comment: sadly doesn't work, the user is still able to use the Tab for some reason, can i disable the whole tab directly without having to disable every object manually, something like TabParent.tabs(index).enabled=false;